# Packaging and running executable JAR from single Gradle build invocation?

Tags: groovy, gradle, gradle-plugin

Here is my Groovy app's driver class:

```
package org.me.myapp

class MyDriver {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        // The p flag was passed in and had a value of 50!
        println String.format("The %s flag was passed in and had a value of %s!", args[0], args[1])
    }
}
```

I am trying to augment my Gradle build so that I can:

1. Have Gradle package up my executable JAR; and
2. Run my executable JAR, passing in command line args to its main method

Ideally, I would be able to simply run my app by:

```
gradle run -p 50
```

And See the following console output:

```
The p flag was passed in and had a value of 50!
```

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
targetCompatibility = '1.7'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile (
        'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9',
        'com.google.guava:guava:18.0',
        'com.google.inject:guice:3.0'
    )
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

**What do I need to do to be able to have Gradle package + run my app like this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute `run` task you need to apply `application` plugin. You can add below snippet to your  `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "org.me.myapp.MyDriver"
run {
    args "p"
    args "50"
}
```

You can replace `"p"` and `"50"` with some gradle property names, and pass those properties from command line like

`gradle run -Pkey=p -Pvalue=50`

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep Gupta (+1) - how would I access those Gradle property names in the code, something like `System.getProperty("key")`?

Comment: No. You can access them directly 

`run {
    args key
    args value
}`

The properties set using `-P<key>=<value>` are added as project properties.